# Show grid or similar equivalent to showframe

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm adjusting some text with `\vfill` and `\vspace{}`. I want a better orientation, so I think, that a package which displays a grid (or gridlines) over the hole page would be great. Or a package, what displays a `X` (corner to corner), to see the exact middle of the page.

Analogously to `\usepackage{show frame}`

**UPDATE:**
Here my MWE, including everything, which is needed to solve my problem...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
dummy
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE!

Comment: If you really think, that this helps...

Comment: Actually, yes. It saves doing the boring bit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always provide an MWE.

`eso-pic` offers various options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[grid]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: gridded Kant]